# WebStorm: When working with remote files, "Error: Could not save project: null"

Tags: webstorm

I'm having a problem with WebStorm only when working with files that are on a mapped drive. I can work with / save files with no problem, but I do get an error prompt saying Could Not Save Project: null.

This happens if I either work in a director or project on a different drive. I have sufficient rights on that drive. Files save fine, but are followed by the error. I have tried completely creating a project on a remote drive instead of having moved it from local, and still receive the same message.

I am a Mac installation, and the files are on a Windows 2K8 box.

All other editors (textmate, aptana, vs) do not give me any indication that I have problems saving to this drive, so it seems to be localized to WebStorm.

WebStorm is on the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapped drives are strictly unsupported by WebStorm. Please file an issue with idea.log attached at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WI so that this problem can be investigated by WebStorm developers.

Answer (score 2):

As CrazyCoder says, its unsupported. I'm having the same problem with PhpStorm and posted this:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10692?projectKey=WI

The response from jetbrains:

> Directly opening project from remote/mapped storage is unsupported.
>   Use "new project from existing files" wizard to create a local copy
>   and set up auto sync.